# How can I remove the existing icon and show only custom icon in the status column for dehydrated file in windows cloud sync engine

Tags: synchronization, cloud

How can I remove the existing icon and show only custom icon in the status column for dehydrated file .Currently when I am trying to display custom icon multiple icon are getting displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0vHJ.png)

tried adding  StorageProviderItemProperty.

var prop = new StorageProviderItemProperty{Id = 1,Value = "Value1",IconResource = "shell32.dll,-44"};